# OnTouchListener on Activity never calls

Tags: android

I used this code, but when i click on activity at runtime, it never hits in OnTouch() method. Can someone guide me what i am doing wrong? Should i need to setcontentview of this activity? Actually i want the coordinates of activity where user touch during execution.

```
public class TouchTestAppActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener 
{ 

    @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       { 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
       //setContentView(R.layout.touch); 
       } 

    @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) 
       { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        String test = "hello";  
       } 
}
```

Answer (score 12):

UPDATE:

You need to do this :

- In your XML layout file, you need an ID for the root view: `android:id="@+id/myView"`
- In youer onCreate() method, write this:

  ```
  LinearView v= (LinearView) findViewById(R.id.myView);
  v.setOnTouchListener(this);
  ```

Assuming that your root view is a `LinearView`

Comment: sorry. `setOnTouchListener(this)`

Comment: You can NOT have it for activity. It is for View !

Comment: I updated it again. This answer assumes your root layout is `LinearLayout`. It will work for others after you edit the code slightly. Hope this help. Good Luck !

Answer (score 2):

You should the onTouchListener to relevant GUI components.

For example:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   { 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
       setContentView(R.layout.touch); 
       TextView someView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.some_view_from_layout_xml);
       someView.setOnTouchListener(this); // "this" is the activity which is also OnTouchListener
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a the listener using `setOnTouchListener()` otherwise who will give call to your onTouch method. any listener works on any view. so you have to add the listener to the view eg  `button.setOnTouchListener(this);`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourxml, null);
setCOntentView(vi);
vi.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

In onCreate, you need to set the content view (just uncommenting the second line should probably work) and then you need to set your OnTouchListener (your activity) as the onTouchListener for a view in your application.

Let's say you've got a view in your layout called "MainView"; it would look something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      View view = findViewById(R.id.MainView);
      view.setOnTouchListener(this);
   }
```

This article has a good example:
http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-2-building-the-touch-example/1763